# JFileChooser show multiple selected files in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jfilechooser

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
   File[] files = fc.getSelectedFiles();

   private void showTxtFileFrame() {
       fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
       fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
       int result = fc.showOpenDialog(this);   
       if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            textfield1.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

I want to select multiple files and have them listed on my text field. I am able to selected multiple files but it only shows the absolute path of a single file.

Comment: See edits to answer please.

Answer (score 5):

For one thing, I'd display the multiple file paths in a GUI component better suited to show multiple objects such as a JList. For another, the [JFileChooser API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) will tell you which method returns just a single File and which returns an array of `File[]`: `getSelectedFiles()`. Note the `s` on the end.

But of course, you can't put an array into a JTextField, but I'm guessing that you know what to do with the data once you get it.

Also, this makes no sense:

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
File[] files = fc.getSelectedFiles();
```

Since you're actually calling `getSelectedFiles()` before displaying the file chooser dialog. What you want to do is to call that method **within** your `showTxtFileFrame()` method, just as you're currently calling `getSelectedFile()`.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JFileChooserExample extends JPanel {
    // use a list model and JList that works *directly* with Files
    private DefaultListModel<File> fileListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<File> fileJList = new JList<>(fileListModel);

    public JFileChooserExample() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new SelectFilesAction("Select Files", KeyEvent.VK_S)));

        // help set the width and height of the JList
        fileJList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        fileJList.setPrototypeCellValue(new File("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(fileJList);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private class SelectFilesAction extends AbstractAction {
        public SelectFilesAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
            fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
            int result = fc.showOpenDialog(JFileChooserExample.this);   
            if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                fileListModel.clear();  // clear the model of prior files
                 File[] files = fc.getSelectedFiles();
                 for (File file : files) {
                     // add all files to the model
                    fileListModel.addElement(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFileChooserExample mainPanel = new JFileChooserExample();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFileChooser Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```